# Destroying label frames

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am tinkering around with basic things in Tkinter/python. I am using the LabelFrame that corresponds with several buttons I click. I am struggling with trying to destroy the other frames and only displaying the frame I want visible when clicking on a certain button. When I run this code:

```
def lblframe1_view():
    lblframe3.destroy()
    lblframe2.destroy()
    lblframe1 = LabelFrame(root, text="This is Frame One", height=370, width=370, bd=5, relief=FLAT).place(x=215, y=20)
    btn1 = Button(lblframe1, text="this is button one").pack()


def lblframe2_view():
    lblframe1.destroy()
    lblframe3.destroy()
    lblframe2 = LabelFrame(root, text="Frame Two", height=370, width=370, bd=5, relief=FLAT).place(x=215, y=20)
    btn2 = Button(lblframe2, text="this is button two").pack()


def lblframe3_view():
    lblframe1.destroy()
    lblframe2.destroy
    lblframe3 = LabelFrame(root, text="this is frame 3", height=370, width=370, bd=5, relief=FLAT).place(x=215, y=20)



def exit():
    root.destroy()

manbtn1 = Button(root, text="Frame 1", bg="white", height=4, width=25, command=lblframe1).place(x=10, y=20)
mainbtn2 = Button(root, text="Frame 2, bg="white", height=4, width=25, command=lblframe2).place(x=10, y=120)
mainbtn3 = Button(root, text="Frame 3", bg="white", height=4, width=25, command=lblframe3).place(x=10, y=220)
exitbtn = Button(root, text="Exit", bg="white", height=4, width=25, command=exit).place(x=10, y=320)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

NameError: name 'lblframe3' is not defined

I have tried to put the functions after buttons and got the same error. I have done research on this 
and haven't been able to figure out why this keeps happening. My hunch is python

Comment: You're using local variables, so `lblframe3` is only available in the function that creates it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not a experienced python programmer myself but there are a few things i noticed that might help you out.

1. Please make sure the code you post here is tested, it is a bit annoying if i have to debug the code before i can help you in the first place. (referring to the " in third line from the bottom as well as the indentation).
2. `Button(command)` takes a function as a argument. You provided a Object. So try to switch the command to `command = lblframe1_view` instead of `lblframe1`.
3. Frames in tkinter are objects, therefore they can not be accessed from a function where they were not defined in, unless u declare them global or pass it in as a argument. What that  means is if `lblframe1_view()` is called, it does not know what `lblframe3` or `lblframe2` are.

I hope this helped you out.

---

EDIT:
I just realised that there might be one more problem with the structure of your programm that can not be solved by declaring the frames as globals. 
In `lblframe1_view` u want to destroy an object that does not even exist yet, since it only will be created if `lblframe2_view()` and `lblframe3_view()` have been executed beforehand. But those two functions will also throw an error, since `lblframe1` is not created yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do some research and found the answer I was looking for: I credit sentdex from Youtube for this. He basically stacks the frames on top of one another and a button click actually calls up the frame based on the command.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


LARGE_FONT = ("verdana", 12)



class tool(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="supporticon.ico")

    self.geometry("400x400")
    self.resizable(0,0)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)



    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") 
        frame.config(bg="darkblue")


    self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    homeframe = LabelFrame(self, text="testing this out", width=200, height=350)
    homeframe.config(background="darkblue", fg="white")
    homeframe.pack()
    label = Label(homeframe, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.config(background="darkblue", fg="white", height=400, width=450)
    label.place(x=10, y=20)

    button1 = ttk.Button(homeframe, text="Vist Page 1", 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
    button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()


app = tool()
app.resizabe=(0,0)
app.geometry=("450x450")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I credit sentdex from Youtube for this"_ - he stole the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050